# Place 10 Coins Heads Up Blindfolded

Tags: probability

You are blindfolded and 10 coins are placed in front of you on table. You are allowed to touch the coins, but can’t tell which way up they are by feel. You are told that there are 5 coins head up, and 5 coins tails up but not which ones are which. How do you make two piles of coins each with the same number of heads up? You can flip the coins any number of times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Divide them into two groups of 5, then flip all the coins in one group. The group you flip had n heads in it, and the other group had 5-n. When you flip the coins, the first group now has 5-n heads as well.

Answer (score 1):

Create two piles with 0 coins each. Each pile contains no heads and no tails